# Range variable setting empty value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I'm trying to pull data from a feed and loop each piece of data into A1:D1 on a worksheet labeled RawData, then move to A2:D2 for the next set of data.  I've reused code from a previous VBA project I had and it works fine, this one doesn't so not sure what I'm missing.

The error I get is `Application defined or object-defined error` and happens at the first instance of:  `Sheets("RawData").range(rCurrentCell).value =`

The `debug.print` output is correct for each `xNode` so the data it's setting is correct.

I think it's actually breaking when setting the value for `rFirstCell` and `rCurrentCell`.  Printing these lines yields empty values.

Originally I was using `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` for referencing other things and was getting an object error so switched over to using the `ws` object instead.

My previous code snippet for setting `rFirstCell` was:

```
'Set initial values for Range Pointers
 Set rFirstCell = Worksheets("RawData").range("A1")
 Set rCurrentCell = rFirstCell
```

`Full Code:`

```
Sub ReadFromAcumatica()
Dim xmlReq As ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rFirstCell As Range 'Points to the First Cell in the row currently being updated
Dim rCurrentCell As Range 'Points the the current cell in the row being updated
Dim counter As Integer 'Counts the lines

counter = 0

'Clear Existing Data

 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData").Cells.Delete

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData")

 'Set initial values for Range Pointers
 Set rFirstCell = ws.Range("A1")
 Set rCurrentCell = rFirstCell

'Connect to server to pull data.
Set xmlReq = New ServerXMLHTTP60
xmlReq.Open "GET", "https://somewebsite.com", False, "username", "password"
xmlReq.send

Dim xmlStr As String
Dim XPath As String

xmlStr = xmlReq.responseText

' Create document object
Set objDom = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")     '// Using MSXML 3.0

'/* Load XML */
objDom.LoadXML xmlStr
objDom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
"xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' " & _
"xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata'"

Set xNodes = objDom.getElementsByTagName("m:properties")
    
    For Each xNode In xNodes
        If xNode.ChildNodes.Length <> 1 Then
            Debug.Print xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:OrderNbr").text, xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:InventoryID").text & _
            xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Description").text, xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Quantity").text, xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:RequestedOn").text

           'xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:OrderNbr").text
           
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1) 'move current cell one column right
                Sheets("RawData").Range(rCurrentCell).Value = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:InventoryID").text
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1) 'move current cell one column right
                Sheets("RawData").Range(rCurrentCell).Value = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Description").text
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1) 'move current cell one column right
                Sheets("RawData").Range(rCurrentCell).Value = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Quantity").text
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1) 'move current cell one column right
                Sheets("RawData").Range(rCurrentCell).Value = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:RequestedOn").text
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(1, -4) 'move current to next line
                        
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `rCurrentCell` is range object. Using `rCurrentCell.Value = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:InventoryID").Text`

Comment: btw, `.Cells.Clear` is more efficient than `.Cells.Delete`.

Comment: I feel like a moron @taller_ExcelHome.  I looked at the code so long I was going cross eyed and it was the obvious...

Answer (score 2):

A much cleaner code. Don't forget to close this question.

```
Sub ReadFromAcumatica()
Dim xmlReq As ServerXMLHTTP60
Dim ws As Worksheet
'Dim rFirstCell As Range 'Points to the First Cell in the row currently being updated
Dim rCurrentCell As Range 'Points the the current cell in the row being updated
Dim counter As Integer 'Counts the lines

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("RawData")
counter = 0

'Clear Existing Data
ws.Cells.Clear

 'Set initial values for Range Pointers
 'Set rFirstCell = ws.Range("A1")
 Set rCurrentCell = ws.Range("A1")

'Connect to server to pull data.
Set xmlReq = New ServerXMLHTTP60
xmlReq.Open "GET", "https://somewebsite.com", False, "username", "password"
xmlReq.send

Dim xmlStr As String
Dim XPath As String

xmlStr = xmlReq.responseText

' Create document object
Set objDom = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")     '// Using MSXML 3.0

'/* Load XML */
objDom.LoadXML xmlStr
objDom.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", _
"xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' " & _
"xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata'"

Set xNodes = objDom.getElementsByTagName("m:properties")
    
    For Each xNode In xNodes
        If xNode.ChildNodes.Length <> 1 Then
            Debug.Print xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:OrderNbr").text, xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:InventoryID").text & _
            xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Description").text, xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Quantity").text, xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:RequestedOn").text

           'xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:OrderNbr").text
           
            rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 1) = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:InventoryID").text
            rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 2) = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Description").text
            rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 3) = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:Quantity").text
            rCurrentCell.Offset(0, 4) = xNode.SelectSingleNode("d:RequestedOn").text
            Set rCurrentCell = rCurrentCell.Offset(1, 0) 'move current to next line
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: **(1)** OP didn't ask for cleaner code, they asked why a certain line throws an error. You fail to explain that. **(2)** If you state that your code is cleaner, you should explain at least a little bit why you think so. **(3)** Your code obviously doesn't use `Option Explicit` - some variable definitions are missing, while you declare others that are (no longer) used - not what I would call clean.  **(4)** On SO, you don't close questions. The OP can accept an answer, but that doesn't mean the question is *closed*. It can still receive answers, and OP can later accept another answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Always trying to learn some different methods.  I can integrate this into my code.

Comment: @FunThomas - (1) I like to do that little extra, because it's appreciated. (2) I used the declared ws, I comment some rows that's not needed and I cleaned up the use of Offset. (3) I do use Option Explicit and I diden't declare anything new. I guessed the "counter" is going to be used or is removed in this example. FunThomas, I wish you could put your energy on helping instead of being negative to me. Travis, good luck with your codeing!

Comment: I put *a lot* of energy in helping (look at my profile). But helping means also to ask people to improve the quality of their answers. You answer contains only code and explains nothing which is not the idea of SO. That said: Your routine misses 3 variable declarations. I wouldn't accept this in a code review.